# How can I use scratch to search through tags (function definitions) in a project?

Tags: code

When working with sublime I can search through tags using f12 and in vim also there is Ctrl+]. How do I get a similar functionality in 'Scratch', the native editor of elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such functionality. If you want to have such an function, feel free to file an issue over there in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+filebug